# Find a Basis for the subspace S of Vector Space V

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

What is the method for finding a general solution?

For example.

```
Let S be the subspace of V, where V = all [2x2] symmetric matrices. 
So A transpose(A^t) = A.
```

What is a Basis for subspace S? I can't find an examples of this. I have been trying to use properties of Linearly Independant Combo's and Vector Spaces but I'm coming up with a whole lot of nonsense.

Comment: I just want to point out that you should not say "What is *the* basis for subspace $S$" (instead say *a* basis) since there are many basis for any vector space except the trivial subspace $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\text{Hint:}\\
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} &...& a_{1n} \\
        a_{12} & a_{22} &...& a_{2n} \\
...&...&...&...\\
        a_{1n} & a_{2n} &...& a_{nn} \\
        \end{pmatrix}
=\left\{a_{11}\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 &...& 0 \\
        0 & 0 &...& 0 \\
...&...&...&...\\
        0&0&...&0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}+a_{22}\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 &...& 0 \\
        0 & 1 &...& 0 \\
...&...&...&...\\
        0&0&...&0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}+...+a_{nn}\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 &...& 0 \\
        0 & 0 &...& 0 \\
...&...&...&...\\
        0&0&...&1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\right\}+\left\{a_{12}\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 &...& 0 \\
        1 & 0 &...& 0 \\
...&...&...&...\\
        0&0&...&0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}+...+a_{1n}\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 &...& 1 \\
        0 & 0 &...& 0 \\
...&...&...&...\\
        1&0&...&0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\right\}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Show that a basis of the symmetric $2\times 2$-matrices is given by $$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},\quad \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},\quad \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\right\}.$$